# Calling Laravel Controller-function from within custom artisan-command -> unknown database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've created a custom artisan-command in order to call a controller-function via commandline (without curl). 
Since there seems to be no way in Laravel 4 to directly call the function I'm dispatching a request like this:

```
public function fire()
{
    $request = Request::create('insert', 'GET', array());
    Route::dispatch($request)->getContent();
}
```

When I call the command via command-line it starts showing the HTML-content the controller-function would output:

```
php artisan myApp:customCommand
<h1>Insert into Database</h1>
<pre>
```

but then returns this error:

> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'appdatabase'

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was a wrong database-configuration. For some reasons php artisan needs the port-number of the MySQL-server in the hostname of the database-configuration. The web-application itself only works without specifying the port number.

Since that is a more general problem, I created another question regarding that.
[Artisan-commands need different hostname in db-config than Laravel itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331155/artisan-commands-need-different-hostname-in-db-config-than-laravel-itself)

Thanks for the feedback regarding the web-application's structure.

Answer (score 2):

The reason there is no way to directly call the function is because you should never be calling a controller function from your artisan command.

You should refactor the controller's functions into its own class+function, then call that class+function from either your controller or your artisan command.

Comment: I understand as much but will that give me the database-access I need?

Comment: depends how you have your application configured. When calling an artisan command - you can use the `--env` command to specifically pick which environment you want to use, and thus which database you connect to