# Artisan-commands need different hostname in db-config than Laravel itself

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, laravel-4

This is a strange one I've never been able to solve ever since I started using Laravel.

When I issue artisan-commands like 'php artisan migrate' in my db-config (I'm using MySQL via MAMP) the host line has to be:

```
'host' => 'localhost:8889',
```

However when loading a page in the web-browser I get:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:8889'
```

It magically works when I change it to:

```
'host' => 'localhost',
```

On the live-server I'm running the application on I don't have this problem.
What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely happening because you just cd'd into the directory using Terminal and ran the `php artisan migrate` command from there. You'll need to ssh into your vagrant box using `vagrant ssh`, then navigate to your project folder and run the migrate command from there.

Answer (score 0):

What port is your MySQL server running on locally?  By default, MySQL looks for a server on :3306, so you'll get the error unless something is there to serve it or re-direct it

My guess is the prod server is running MySQL on :8889 and your local environment is running MySQL on :3306

In your local environment, You could either change the port to 8889:
http://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/#q11

Or forward the port:
http://www.chrisvanpatten.com/port-forwarding-mavericks